# Correcting Muddled Dates in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a million-row time-series dataframe, in which some of the values in the Date column have muddled day/month values.

How do I efficiently unmuddle them without also ruining those that are correct?

---

```
# this creates a dataframe with muddled dates

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp

start = Timestamp(2013,1,1)
dates = pd.date_range(start, periods=942)[::-1]

muddler = {}
for d in dates:
    if d.day < 13:
        muddler[d] = Timestamp(d.year, d.day, d.month)
    else:
        muddler[d] = Timestamp(d.year, d.month, d.day)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = dates
df['Date'] =  df['Date'].map(muddler)

# now what? (assuming I don't know how the dates are muddled)
```

Comment: What day would `2020/05/06` be: `Jun 05` or `May 06`?

Comment: pandas' Timestamp(2020,5,6) would be the 6th of May.

In the case of my dataset it all seems to be in order (apart from the problem of muddled months/days), so if one has the time/inclination to go through it manually, one could establish by comparison with surrounding dates what the answer should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option might be to calculate a fit for the timestamps and modify those that deviate from the fit greater than a certain threshold. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = pd.Timestamp(2013,1,1)
dates = pd.date_range(start, periods=942)[::-1]

muddler = {}
for d in dates:
    if d.day < 13:
        muddler[d] = pd.Timestamp(d.year, d.day, d.month)
    else:
        muddler[d] = pd.Timestamp(d.year, d.month, d.day)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = dates
df['Date'] =  df['Date'].map(muddler)

# convert date col to posix timestamp
df['ts'] = df['Date'].values.astype(np.float) / 10**9

# calculate a linear fit for ts col
x = np.linspace(df['ts'].iloc[0], df['ts'].iloc[-1], df['ts'].size)
df['ts_linfit'] = np.polyval(np.polyfit(x, df['ts'], 1), x)

# set a thresh and derive a mask that masks differences between 
# fit and timestamp greater than thresh:
thresh = 1.2e6 # you might want to tweak this...
m = np.absolute(df['ts']-df['ts_linfit']) > thresh

# create new date col as copy of original
df['Date_filtered'] = df['Date']

# modify values that were caught in the mask
df.loc[m, 'Date_filtered'] = df['Date_filtered'][m].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x.year, x.day, x.month))

# also to posix timestamp
df['ts_filtered'] = df['Date_filtered'].values.astype(np.float) / 10**9


ax = df['ts'].plot(label='original')
ax = df['ts_filtered'].plot(label='filtered')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really interesting approach. Thankyou!

Comment: @PeterPrescott: it should definitely be more efficient than iterating the date column. However, the fit might need some tweaking so that it works reliable for your application. Ideally, create some test cases with prescribed output.

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to create a minimal reproducible example, I have actually solved my problem -- but I expect there is a more efficient and effective way to do what I'm trying to do...

---

```
# i first define a function to examine the dates

def disordered_muddle(date_series, future_first=True):
    """Check whether a series of dates is disordered or just muddled"""
    disordered = []
    muddle = []
    dates = date_series
    different_dates = pd.Series(dates.unique())
    date = different_dates[0]
    for i, d in enumerate(different_dates[1:]):
        # we expect the date's dayofyear to decrease by one
        if d.dayofyear!=date.dayofyear-1:
            # unless the year is changing
            if d.year!=date.year-1:
                try:
                    # we check if the day and month are muddled
                    # if d.day > 12 this will cause an Exception
                    unmuddle = Timestamp(d.year,d.day,d.month)
                    if unmuddle.dayofyear==date.dayofyear-1:
                        muddle.append(d)
                        d = unmuddle
                    elif unmuddle.year==date.year-1:
                        muddle.append(d)
                        d = unmuddle
                    else:
                        disordered.append(d)
                except:
                    disordered.append(d)
        date=d
    if len(disordered)==0 and len(muddle)==0:
        return False
    else:
        return disordered, muddle

disorder, muddle = disordered_muddle(df['Date'])

# finally unmuddle the dates
date_correction = {}

for d in df['Date']:
    if d in muddle:
        date_correction[d] = Timestamp(d.year, d.day, d.month)
    else:
        date_correction[d] = Timestamp(d.year, d.month, d.day)

df['CorrectedDate'] = df['Date'].map(date_correction)

disordered_muddle(df['CorrectedDate'])
```